# Radio buttons in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view which has four cells in each cell i want to create two radio buttons(YES,NO) in such a way that if i select yes then no should be disabled and vice-versa  in a particular cell likewise i want to do in all the four cells. can anybody share the code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons are great for the web where you have a small pointer, but horrible interface for the device and fat fingers. The behavior you are trying to achieve is better represented with a single `UISegmentedControl` (for more than one option) and a `UISwitch` for a `yes|no` option. See [here](http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/home/2009/9/15/here-is-how-you-use-the-segmented-control-uisegmentedcontrol.html) or [here](http://www.xprogress.com/post-30-uiswitch-tutorial-example-how-to-use-the-switch-in-xcode-for-iphone-sample-included/) for a quick tutorial on how to implement them